# In Lab 2(scrabble) of CS50 is there a way for the program I wrote in C to also accept signs symbols etc

Tags: c, cs50

In lab 2 of CS50, the task is to write a program that takes 2 words and calculates the value of each letter in the words(common letters are worth less and rarer letters are worth more) and compares them, then finally shows which word is worth more.
The program should also accept symbols, numbers, punctuations, etc. but they are worth 0. And it should also ignore case of the letters.
In my program it just ignores letter case, but doesnt accept punctuation marks, numbers, etc, Is there a way to make it work

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // TODO: Print the winner
    if(score1 > score2)
    {
        printf("Player 1 wins!\n");
    }
    else if (score2 > score1)
    {
        printf("Player 2 wins!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Tie!\n");
    }
}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    // TODO: Compute and return score for string
    int sum = 0;
    int len = strlen(word);
    int letter_value[len];
    string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    //to convert entire word to lower case
    for (int w = 0; w <= len; w++)
    {
        word[w] = tolower(word[w]);
    }
    
    // to get a array letter_value that has all the letters alphabetic value from 1-26
    int m = 0;
    for (int w = 0; w < len; m++, w++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; word[m] != letters[n]; n++)
        {
            letter_value[m] = n + 1;
        }
    }
    //replaces alphabetic letter values in letter_value array into scrabble values
    int c = 0;
    for (int w = 0; w < len; w++)
    {
        letter_value[w] = POINTS[letter_value[w]];
    }
    //adds all the elements of array letter_value in variable sum.
    for(int w = 0; w < len; w++)
    {
        sum = sum + letter_value[w];
    }

    return(sum);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with you probably shouldn't "remove anyother numbers other than letters". Especially since you're not doing correctly and don't recalculate `len` afterwards.

Instead let all characters in `word` be as they are, and use [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) in the calculation loop to check if a character is a letter or not.

And remember to set all unused elements of `letter_value` to zero (i.e. for all characters that are *not* letters).

Comment: I removed the "remove anyother numbers other than letters" from my code, and I edited it here as well, Idk why its not updated for u.
But Thanks a lot.